# Creating custom UID in React Firebase Module

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

In a React app, when we call the `signInWithCredential` method from the Firebase library, a new user gets created in the Firebase console if it doesn't exist.
When this happens, we need to be able to pass a custom UID to this method.
The issue is that the `createUser` method is not available for this React Firebase library, just for the firebase-admin SDK and moving the logic to the backend is not an option at the moment. Any suggestions on how to pass a custom UID to the firebase auth object?

Comment: There is no way to set the UID of a user from the client-side SDKs for Firebase Authentication. The only way you can set the UID is through the Admin SDK, as you have found, or by creating your own provider. If this was possible in client-side code, anyone could impersonate any other user - which would be a major security risk. --- The only workaround would be to store your own mapping from the UID in Firebase to your own user IDs.